# Database reverse engineer installation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an existing database (SQL Server 2008 R2), and my goal is to have a project that can install the same database as I already have.

i.e the project will read the schema and the data, and will be able to duplicate the existing data and schema.
This tool needs to save the database information to disk so I will able to install the database on different machines.

Can I do it with Visual studio 2010 database projects?
Is it a simple task?

(The reason I am asking is that I already have such a project that installs my database, but this tool is very old(~2000). 
That old project is one big mess, it has C#, java, sql, batch files and some 3rd party tools and has many more capabilities than I need for my current product..)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) to create a snapshot of your source db and then restore it to the target server.

More on SMO here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx . 
A nice tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to backup using SQL server management studio. Then move the backup file to the second server and there restore it with SQL server management studio. If you need SQL code to do it (instead of GUI way), just drop a comment...

Answer (score 1):

This codeplex project has a basic library that does that if you like to roll your own and has two sample projects for migration/comparison tasks.

http://dbschemareader.codeplex.com/

Also the commercial option is to use Sql Redgate's tools. They are expensive but worth every penny if this is a mission critical database. On the otherhand, if you are just using a db as an alternative to a file, say in a embedded scenario, it might be hard to justify such an expensive tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DBSourceTools ? http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com
It is an open-source database versioning tool that will script out all database objects and data to disk, and then re-create the database on another machine.
It has all of the features that you are looking for.